# Why to_sql function is taking more to time to replace a table in MySQL from python?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have to replace a table in mysql for that I have used pymysql to_sql. I have only 100 rows with 30 columns.It is taking more than 6 hours to upload. I have added `method='multi'` parameter but it didn't work for me. Please, help me to solve this. I am searching this from 2 days. None of the solutions are working.

I have tried like below:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:password@hostname/dbname")
conn1 = engine.connect()
```

```
data.to_sql('mysql_table1','dbname',conn1,'replace',method='multi')
```

I have tried with event function in create engine:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
@event.listens_for(engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
       if executemany:
          cursor.fast_executemany = True

data.to_sql('mysql_table1','dbname',engine,'replace')
```

Comment: *I have only 100 rows with 30 columns.It is taking more than 6 hours to upload.* Over 200 second per one row loading? Really? *I have to replace a table in mysql* Do you need: drop old table, create new one and fill it with data? Truncate old data and load new one? Update the data with new values? In what form does new data is provided?

Comment: Are you running this on a Pi Zero that's overheating while on a satellite connection in the middle of the ocean? There's no way an insert should be that slow unless this is a table with 100+ huge BLOB columns per row. Test your server out using a MySQL testing tool first to ensure you've configured it correctly.

Comment: @Akina, I have to drop the old table and update the table with  new values for the same table. That is why I am using `replace' method. 'replace' method first drops the table then create the table then insert the values right? upload will be completed within seconds but I don't know Why it is taking more time.

Comment: *I have to drop the old table and update the table with new values for the same table.* After dropping a table it not exists, and it is impossible to update it. In MySQL at least.. Please be more precise in your words.

Comment: @Akina, I am not dropping the table manually. I have to pull  the table from mysql and performing some changes using python and again I am writing the table back to the database using  'replace' method. This is taking much time.

Comment: If you drop and re-create table then new table is empty. Why you use REPLACE and not INSERT?